# Replace a word by another word in all my Stack Exchange questions and answers

Tags: stack-exchange

I am looking for a program, browser extension or user script that can replace a word by another word in all my Stack Exchange questions and answers.

Any operating system, browser, price or license  is fine.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to edit the posts?  Or copy, put into files or one big file, with the text change?

Comment: @aparente001 I want to edit the posts

Comment: I believe there are macro scripting languages that could do this, such as AutoIT and imacro.  But wouldn't it be easier and cheaper to just pay someone to do it in the usual way, with the brute force approach?  (Unless you are interested in learning to use one of those scripting tools one way or the other, of course.)

Comment: @aparente001 I was hoping some scripts already existed. Definitely should be easy to do oneself.

Comment: Okay, I recommend picking either AutoIT or imacro and posting your question at the specific forum.  You're probably right.  Maybe it would be good to try them both out and then choose the one you feel most comfortable with.  The user experience is rather different between the two.  (I personally have only scratched the surface with both and that was some time ago.  I decided there was too much overhead involved to be able to get to where I would be able to create satisfying macros for casual use.)